# Two-way communication between VSTO add-in and a Task Pane app (JS/HTML)

Tags: vsto, office365, office365-apps, office-js

Is it possible to have a VSTO add-in and a JS/HTML based Task Pane app talk to each other when running inside desktop Office application?

The goal would be to bridge capabilities not yet present (or never will be present) in the x-platform Office APIs using VSTO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Evgene mentioned, there is no out-of-the-box functionality for this (though the topic has certainly come up in internal discussions, so I would be very curious to hear your scenario, and particularly how you would handle the VSTO-only-on-the-desktop case).

If you wanted to try this now, you probably still could with a bit of a creative solution. Imagine you have a hidden sheet with a named range on it, which you use as a communication buffer between VSTO and your taskpane app.

For VSTO => JS communication: have the taskpane create a binding over the named range, then use the binding-data-changed event to listen to an incoming message from your VSTO add-in.

For JS => VSTO communication: have the JS set data to the binding (which, as above, was created over the named range).  On the VSTO side, listen to data changed event, intersect the incoming range with the named range's range, and if the intersection is not null, fetch the text to get the incoming message.

If you do end up trying out this approach, do keep the thread posted on how it went -- I'd be quite curious to hear.

~ Michael Zlatkovsky (developer on Office Extensibility team)

Comment: We are actually looking only looking at the desktop client; and we need the rich UI capabilities that VSTO will enable. Particularly, we need things like floating windows, better management sheets, etc. Basically, more control over the UI. I was hoping for something like a Host Object that we can expose from VSTO/native code to JS. For cross platform code, I suppose, the JS code simply check for this object and ignore irrelevant functionality if it's not available. We'll give your approach a try and see how we can make it work :)

Comment: @Sameera, Sounds good, best of luck!  By the way, if there were some sort of "interop" way for the two to communicate (just trying to understand the scenario & gather food for thought, this in no way says we're committing to anything!), would you imagine that you ship your VSTO add-in and the JS add-in separately (as you'll have to now?).  Advantage is that the JS add-in conceivably can be semi-standalone, but rely on its "big brother".  But it might be trickier to coordinate.  Or would you imagine more of a WinForms-like control that embeds a browser and lets the two communicate?..

Comment: Yes Michael, we are actually striving for a standalone JS add-in that gets a "power-boost" if the VSTO plugin is around :) On the web it'll enable features possible through the confines of the API; on the desktop, it'll work with the VSTO plugin for richer functionality and UX.

Comment: @MichaelZlatkovsky Can we expect anything for communicating between Office Apps and COM add-ins not inventing a wheel by introducing described workarounds?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev, it would be good to understand the exact scenario, and how you envision the communication and deployment happening (same comment as I made to Sameera above).  I would encourage you to start a suggestion on http://officespdev.uservoice.com/ (and post a link back here), describing what exactly you'd envision.  There are likely other higher-priority items that we'll address first, but entering the idea on UserVoice and engaging in a dialog there would be the best way to advance this idea.

Answer (score -1):

Need to admit that VSTO based add-ins can be run only on Windows and desktop clients. Other platforms can't be supported with such scenario.

Anyway, `VSTO` nor `Mail Apps` (based on Office JavaScript API) don't provide anything for that out of the box.