# Bidirectional communication between VSTO add-in and Web add-in

Tags: vsto, outlook-addin, office-js, office-addins

I need to know the way that can communicate between VSTO add-in and Web add-in when the add-ins are running inside desktop Office or Outlook application.

I am developing Office online add-in for desktop version, and because there are so many restrictions, I want to solve the problem through bidirectional communication between VSTO add-in and Web add-in if it is possible.

I am not considering about deployment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Two-way communication between VSTO add-in and a Task Pane app (JS/HTML)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33330872/two-way-communication-between-vsto-add-in-and-a-task-pane-app-js-html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a supported scenario. A Web Add-in runs within a sandbox and completely isolated from the host it's embedded in.

The only possible workaround would be using a common back end and to handle routing commands and events between your Web and VSTO Add-ins yourself. This is effectively how Office.js works as well. It is however an *extremely non-trivial* endeavor.

I would strongly recommend visiting the [UserVoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/) and posting your blockers as suggestions. It is extremely valuable to for Office teams to see exactly which gaps developers are being blocked by in the wild.

Comment: Thank you for answering me. I look for the similar question in stackoverflow [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33330872/two-way-communication-between-vsto-add-in-and-a-task-pane-app-js-html) and would try to implement, but I'm not sure if it would work and even I have something I don't understand.